# Improve the font rendering in Fedora

Tags: fedora, fonts

I was using Ubuntu and recently moved to Fedora 15 with Gnome 3. I am not at all impressed with the subpixel smoothing and fonts in Fedora. How do I improve the readability and quality?

Comment: Have you read http://fedoraunity.org/Members/khaytsus/improve-fonts ?

Comment: Ah yes, Ubuntu uses absolutely beautiful fonts. The first thing I always do after a new Fedora load is setup Ubuntu fonts! Here's the howto: http://blog.andreas-haerter.com/2011/07/18/tune-improve-fedora-fonts-typeface-ubuntu-like-sharp-fonts

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I just found a suitable answer.

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings antialiasing rgba
```

This renders all fonts so much nicer.

To apply the same to the GDM:

```
$ xhost +SI:localuser:gdm 
$ sudo -u gdm gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings antialiasing rgba
```

*Screenshot as requested:*
[image: Comparison between font rendering techniques used by Xserver]

Take note that the difference is more vidible on the actual display.
[Extra reading and explanation.](http://alienryderflex.com/sub_pixel/)

Comment: Can you post some screenshots? it would be helpful.

Comment: @sarat Have a look at http://alienryderflex.com/sub_pixel/ for explanation. Gnome defaults to Grayscale when installed. The above commands set rendering to rgba(sub-pixel) which is only effective on LCD displays.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Cheers :) One more question, is RGBA sub-pixel smoothing is applicable for LED too?

Comment: I'm not that clued up on LED screens, TBH. I would be lying to you if I said yes or no. :) Update your question if this solution doesn't take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

As the cited webpages make clear, this "beautiful font rendering" depends on non-free (patented and propietary) technology, and that is a no-no for Fedora.

Comment: It's not possible to include it in Fedora proper, but it is possible to add it separately after the fact.