# Improve Fedora 17 fonts

Tags: fedora, fonts

Having installed Fedora 17, the fonts still not feel smooth enough...

I've tried [this](http://jaysonrowe.blogspot.com/2012/06/improving-fedora-17-font-rendering.html), and they improved a lot, still I don't get Windows like smoothness.

Using a Java IDE, called intellij so font rendering is very important.

Any ideas on how to get them better? Using 24" display, 1920 x 1200 res

It's basically this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/improve-the-font-rendering-in-fedora) updated for Fedora 17 (procedure there did not make much change)

Here is a sample:

[image]

Here is a Consolas font (In Windows) (is different, I don't have the same font in Linux)

[image]

Comment: Did that... tried to remove hinting with FontForge but could not do it :( Validation error, Fedora does not recognize it.

Comment: Your second image showing the Consolas font looks terrible. The first image is much better. Perhaps one is a low quality JPEG?

Comment: Don't know why, but the second snapshot actually looks great...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](http://blog.andreas-haerter.com/2011/07/18/tune-improve-fedora-fonts-typeface-ubuntu-like-sharp-fonts) instruction on how to change fedoras font-rendering and achieve an ubuntu-like result.

However, there is a specific issue with Java and Linux, or rather with Swing:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402797/swing-font-rendering

Comment: Thx, here was the actual [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/32624/ugly-fonts-in-netbeans-how-can-i-make-it-use-the-system-font)

Comment: Unfortunately, the link broke in the interim.

Comment: The link to a blog post broke. Someone proposed an alternative (is it the same post hosted on a different site?), but this illustrates [why we don't like answers that consist exclusively of a link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please summarize the important points so that your answer is useful even without the link.